# Is it possible for me to change hair in animation?

Tags: geometry-nodes, hair

My question is very simple.  Suppose I have a curly hair in frame 0.  In frame 5 I want it straight.  I can't find any tutorials on this using the new geo node system.  There isn't any shape keys I can save after combing so I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 1):

**Shape Keys for Hair Curves**

If you need shape keys for the new hair system of Blender 3, the "Hair Curves", then you can simply save the different hairstyles/shapes in several curve objects. These will be your "curve shape keys". Then set up a small *Geometry Nodes* tree to create the mixing functionality that Blender provides for (mesh) shape keys.

[image: raised hair example aniamtion]

Here is Suzanne with a shape key named "shocked", and two hairstyles "flat" and "raised".

**Note:** To keep things simple, make sure that both hairstyles have the same number of curves and that the indices are in the same order. That is, duplicate the first hairstyle and create the second hairstyle from it by combing the hair. Do not add/remove hair curves and do not slide the roots.

[image: Geometry Nodes for hair shape keys]

The GN moves the control points of the source/original curves to the control point positions of the given target/alternative curves. It uses the *Index* value to match them. The *Mix* node does the transition. For animation, you can create a keyframe for the *Mix Factor* (yellow) or use a driver.

Answer (score -2):

If you mean straightening the hair, use physics gravity, set the hair to overweight and you're done.

If you want to do it in Geonodes you need to create them as curves, then give them the shape you want.